# Prove an identity for a special sequence with 1 and 2.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $ (K_n)_{n\ge 1} $ be a sequence such that
$$(\forall n\ge 1)\;\; K_n\in\{1,2\}$$

Let $ (S_n)_{n\ge1} $ be the sequence of its partial sums :
$$(\forall n\ge 1)\;\; S_n=\sum_{j=1}^nK_j$$

I have been asked to prove that for $ n\ge1$
$$\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{S_j}K_j=2\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{S_j}+\frac{1-(-1)^{S_n}}{2}$$
I separated the sum into two : for even and odd indices, but i didn't find the rigorous way to get the identity.
Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation for $n$ minus the equation for $n-1$ amounts to
$$\tag1(-1)^{S_n}K_n=2(-1)^{S_n}+\frac{(-1)^{S_{n-1}}-(-1)^{S_n}}{2} $$
As
$$ (-1)^{S_n}=(-1)^{S_{n-1}+K_n}=(-1)^{S_{n-1}}(-1)^{K_n},$$
dividing $(1)$ by $(-1)^{S_n}$ leads to
$$K_n=2+\frac{\frac1{(-1)^{K_n}}-1}{2} $$
which happens to be correct when $K_n=1$ as well as when $K_n=2$. So $(1)$ is true for all $n$, which mena that the original claim follows by inducton on $n$ once we check the base case. This is most easily done by using $n=0$ instead of $n=1$ as base case, i.e., by logically extending the definition of $S_n$ to the case $n=0$ by noting that the $0$th partial sum is empty, hence $S_0=0$.

Comment: Nothing to say : great answer. Thank you.